# @MainActor isn't forcing compiler check when mutating @Observable property on background thread

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-concurrency, mainactor

Why does the below code not create a compiler error?

I am mutating a `@Published` property of this `ObservableObject` on a background thread. Shouldn't the `@MainActor` tag on this class mean that any code which mutates a published property *must* occur on the main thread?

```swift
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
    @Published private(set) var questionnaire: Questionnaire!
    
    init() {
        fetchQuestionnaire(id: "forest")
    }
    
    func fetchQuestionnaire(id: String) {
        Task {
            questionnaire = Questionnaire.testData
        }
    }
    
}
```

Or, is it actually OK to mutate `@Published` properties on a background thread, and SwiftUI will perform the `didSet` publisher on the main thread?

And if that’s the case, what even really is the point of `@MainActor` in this situation?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)): *Unlike Task.detached(priority:operation:), the task created by Task.init(priority:operation:) **inherits the priority and actor context of the caller**, so the operation is treated more like an asynchronous extension to the synchronous operation.*

Answer (score 0):

When you isolate `ViewModel` to the main actor, its methods and properties are isolated to the main actor, too. In fact, this practice of isolating the `ObservableObject` to the main actor is actually recommended in WWDC 2021’s video [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=1290). In that video, they recommend isolating the [`ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject/) being observed by a `View` to the main actor.

And when you use `Task {…}` within an actor isolated method, that creates a new top level task on the current actor (i.e., the main actor). As Vadian pointed out, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye) says (emphasis added):

> [`Task {…}` runs] the given nonthrowing operation asynchronously as part of a new top-level task *on behalf of the current actor.*

So, bottom line, you are not updating this on a “background thread”. You are updating it on the main actor. Hence, no compiler errors and no runtime warnings from the main thread checker.